# C# - How do create a defined parts of bundle threads from a thread array

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

I have a list box with several items. I'm looking for a simple way to run each time a specific number of thread bundle. How Do I control if my bundle of thread has ended and I should start the next bundle.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewEx1.CheckedItems)
{                                      
     vList.Add((V)item.Tag);

     Thread tr = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Deploy));
     threads.Add(tr);
     tr.Start((object)item.Tag);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) to countdown the number of running threads and have the threads release their semaphore claim.

That said, I'd go for a different setup:

- put this kind of thread management in a separate class (not tied to the UI)
- Leave the creation of threads to the runtime by using the Task Parallel Library, create [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and leave bundling to the runtime (takes away a lot of management code and scales to the hardware.

Comment: Thanks so much on the help, Can you please attached s code snippet to demonstrate it for me.

Comment: To demonstrate what? I hope you understand that I am not going to write your code. Try to do it yourself and if/when you get stuck feel free to ask for help.

Comment: I resolve my issue by using Semaphore to limit the number of running threads.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use BackgroundWorker?

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

if (bw.IsBusy != true)
{
   bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
if (bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
{
   bw.CancelAsync();
}
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) { }
private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) { }
private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) { }
```

When the `bw_RunWorkerCompleted` event is raised then you know that your thread is over.

Comment: Hi Thanks on the efforts. So For each new Thread will create a new bw object , the BW will replace regular threads.

Comment: My opinion is to replace your threads with background workers if it's possible. I don't think that it's a good practice to create a background worker for each thread(too many threads!).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET framework 4.0, you could use parallel LINQ:

```
// First, fill the vList-collection.
vList.AddRange(listView1.CheckedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(item => (V)item.Tag));
// Second, for each item, call Deploy, but do this parallel.
listView1.CheckedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().AsParallel().ForAll(item => Deploy(item.Tag));
```

(Since I did not have all the code (like `Deploy`, and `vList`) I am not sure if it will compile, but this is just a direction.)

Comment: Thanks on the help. Deploy is just the method I doing my code in the thread. vList is a List of objects :  List<VM> vmList = new List<VM>();

Comment: What is `VM`? Is VM different than `V`? Well, it does not really matter, I was just trying to point to you in the direction of `AsParallel`.

Comment: Hi , sorry V is VM , missed it, VM is a class.